# Is there any API for VMware Compatibility Guide?

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

Following link provides VMware's compatibility with Ontap device(IMT)
https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php

It returns IMT data on click of button:"Update and view result", I want to fetch the same data using python script, so need APIs for the same.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the VMware Compatibility Guide API is private at this point in time.